# How to regex and get file and directory path

Tags: perl

My array (@array) contains these directory structures. below directory and files path.

```
/home/testuser/mysql/data/userdata/pushdir/
/home/testuser/mysql/data/userdata/pushdir/test1.sql
/home/testuser/mysql/data/userdata/nextdir/testdir/
/home/testuser/mysql/data/userdata/pushdir/testdir/test2.sql

 /home/testuser/mysql/data/userdata/ - from above list till this line path is constant.
```

I am trying to process the files to another loop . for that I am looking for the file names output only like "pushdir/test1.sql"  and "pushdir/testdir/test2.sql"

I am using this code to get that, but I am not getting the expected output like "pushdir/test1.sql"  and "pushdir/testdir/test2.sql". Please share your ideas to regex and get the output

```
foreach $dir(@array)
{
chomp $dir;
print "$dir\n";
@files = <$dir/*>;
my @names=join("\n", sort(@files));
print @names,"\n";
}

foreach my $filepath (@names) {

  (my $volume,my $dirs, my $filelist) = File::Spec->splitpath(+$filepath );
  print "$filelist\n";
 }
```

Comment: There's no regex anywhere. There's only a glob wildcard.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` would have advised you to this error.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: Hi Jacob, I am trying to get the filename (full path of the file names) and dirname/filename alone (like from file path I am looking for output  "pushdir/test1.sql" and "pushdir/testdir/test2.sql")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@names` is declared with [my](http://p3rl.org/my), and therefore scoped inside the `foreach $dir` loop only. There's no `@names` array to iterate over in the second foreach loop. Moreover, [join](http://p3rl.org/join)
returns a string, you probably don't want the string to go to the array, you want individual filesnames to go there.

Use [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict) (it will tell you there's no `@names` declared) and [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings). Indent code blocks properly to see what commands belong where.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Spec;

my @array = qw( home/testuser/mysql/data/userdata/pushdir/
                home/testuser/mysql/data/userdata/pushdir/test1.sql
                home/testuser/mysql/data/userdata/nextdir/testdir/
                home/testuser/mysql/data/userdata/pushdir/testdir/test2.sql );

my @names;
for my $dir (@array) {
    print "DIR: $dir\n";
    push @names, sort glob "$dir/*";
    print "NAMES: @names\n";
}

for my $filepath (@names) {
    my ($volume, $dirs, $filelist) = 'File::Spec'->splitpath($filepath);
    print "FL: $filelist\n";
}
```

Comment: hi,  it works partially.  I am not sure if I am missing . however, I am not getting the filenames (with full path) from @array . sort glob "$dir/*"  results system files list. I am actually trying to get  filename (full path of the file names) and dirname/filename alone (like from file path I am looking for output "pushdir/test1.sql" and "pushdir/testdir/test2.sql") . thanks

Comment: @organic: Use `abs2rel` to get relative path. Also, shouldn't `test2.sql` be located in `nextdir` instead of `pushdir`?

Comment: hi, thanks. yes test2.sql is located at "/home/testuser/mysql/data/userdata/nextdir/testdir/"